# Difference between JDK 32 bits and 64 bits

Tags: java

I am beginner to `Java` , I would like to know is there any difference between `JDK 32 bit` and `64 bit`?

e.g.in terms of performance or in any other aspect?

Comment: You can address more memory...kind of par for the course with most 64-bit applications.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but keep in mind that that's only a runtime issue; the code you write is identical. For most applications, using a 64-bit JVM will result in improved performance, but it's dependent on the specifics of what you're doing.